# Chapter Title overlaps logo in header

Tags: formatting, header-footer, overlap

I'm writing my thesis and I have to insert a chapter title that is very long. The problem is that in the header of the pages, it overleaps the logo like the following
[image]

Any idea to fix this? thanks

Comment: \chapter[short]{very long title}

Comment: thanks! It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general

```
\chapter[short]{main}
```

will use `short` in the ToC and header and `main` as the title on the chapter page.

In case you need more flexibility the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) provides two optional arguments:

```
\chapter[toc-title][head-title]{title} % three different texts
\chapter[toc-and-head-title]{title} % two different texts
\chapter{title} % one text for ToC, header and main title
```